# How can I share a function in a react-redux connected component with other components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a function (initialize) defined in a React component that dispatches a bunch of redux actions.

```js
import { setData, doThing, doSomethingElse } from "redux/actions";
import { fetchData } from "services/api";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Basic extends Component {
  initialize = () => {
    const { setData, doThing, doSomethingElse } = this.props;
    if (someLogic) {
      doThing();
    } else {
      doSomethingElse();
    }
    fetchData.then(data => setData(data));
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.initialize();
  }

  render() {
    const { loading } = this.props;
    if (loading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    return <div>Content</div>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ state }) => ({
  loading: state.loading
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  setData,
  doThing,
  doSomethingElse
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Basic);
```

This works fine in this scenario, but as I'm developing my app I realize I might want to call 'initialize' in several other components as well. What would be the best way for me to extract this function for re-usability in other components?

I'm tempted extract it into a helper function like this:

```js
import store from "redux/store";

export function initializeHelper() {
  if (someLogic) {
    store.dispatch(doThing());
  } else {
    store.dispatch(doSomethingElse());
  }
  fetchData.then(data => store.dispatch(setData(data)));
}
```

And it does work, since the store I'm importing in the helper function is the same store provided in my React app. However, it feels wrong tocall the store directly like this.

Another thing I've tried is using a render prop component that just passes the function as follows:

```js
class Initialize extends Component {
  initialize = () => {
    const { setData, doThing, doSomethingElse } = this.props;
    if (someLogic) {
      doThing();
    } else {
      doSomethingElse();
    }
    fetchData.then(data => setData(data));
  };

  render() {
    return this.props.children(this.initialize)
  }
}

// Wrap any component to pass the function as a prop

<Initialize>
  {initialize => <OtherComponent initialize={initialize} />}
</Initialize>
```

But this also feels like the wrong use of the render prop pattern, as the render prop is not sharing any state. It's just sharing a function that primarily dispatches redux actions.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Note: I am not yet planning to use React hooks in my current project.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's best practice but I have an approach [here](https://github.com/ibarapascal/netbooks/blob/master/src/components/books/common/BKService.tsx)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the external helper function calling `store.dispatch` approach. That's a perfectly valid way of doing it, and probably the simplest/cleanest approach

Comment: Make it a custom hook. only works in FC though or put it in a middleware.

Comment: @keikai Can you explain your approach / code? I'm not too familiar with TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Higher Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html). As per the docs: 'A higher-order component (HOC) is an advanced technique in React for reusing component logic' which is exactly what you are trying to do.

A Higher Order Component which will share the desired behavior across your components might look like this:

```
const withInit = (componentToWrap) => (props) => { 
  useEffect(() => { 
    // something to execute on mount
  },[])

  return <componentToWrap {...props}/>
}
```

The docs provide ways to do achieve this with classes as well. Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem I have with using a HOC or render prop in this scenario is that there is no react-specific logic being shared with the child component. It is simply passing a single function (that doesn't care about react state etc) down to the child component. It should pretty much just be imported as a helper function instead, but as I mentioned in my post, I was unsure if using store.dispatch() directly was advisable.

Comment: HOCs do not necessarily have to execute any react-specific code, one of their main goals is code reutilization...  I suppose the helper function approach is fine too as long as you know what you're doing. There is an interesting article on this: https://daveceddia.com/access-redux-store-outside-react/.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case of [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html). You have a repetitive pattern of initializing the data.
This peace of code can be extracted out in an HOC(Higher Order Component), a function which will take component to be rendered in one of its argument.
This HOC will do the initialization stuff for your component and render the component with subscribed data as props to the component. (In case you need. You have not used it in your example)

*HOC will be connected to the redux and child component need not be connected*

Lets look into the code.

```
import { setData, doThing, doSomethingElse } from "redux/actions";
import { fetchData } from "services/api";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const InitializeOnMount = (Component) => {

   class InitializerComponent extends Component {

     initialize = () => {
      const { setData, doThing, doSomethingElse } = this.props;
      if (someLogic) {
        doThing();
      } else {
        doSomethingElse();
      }
      fetchData.then(data => setData(data));
     };

     componentDidMount() {
       this.initialize();
     }

     render() {
       const { loading } = this.props;
       if (loading) {
         return <div>Loading...</div>;
       }
       return <Component />;
     }
   }

   const mapStateToProps = ({ state }) => ({
     loading: state.loading
   });

   const mapDispatchToProps = {
     setData,
     doThing,
     doSomethingElse
   };

   return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(InitializerComponent);
};

export {InitializeOnMount};
```